# Magento Shipping Methods not found

Tags: magento

I have a magento with 2 stores. Store 1 is fully functional and uses the default shipping methods.

When we cloned the first store and added a new layout and new products, the checkout process tells me that there is no shipping method available, but I can see it as activated in the settings for this store in the magento configuration area.

Store 1 remains fully functional, only store 2 doesn't work as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: It is definitely enabled at the store level not using Website or Global scope? Have you cleared all the caches?

Comment: It is enabled on the global, website and on the store level in settings -> shipping methods (looks like the same as for the first store). 

All caches are deactivated and I cleared them - no success

Comment: what shipping method are you using? one of Magento's native? If it's the tablerate, you should import the csv in the new store, as rates are set by store.

Comment: The re-import of the table rates fixed it - thanks!